# How do I write a simple Ragel tokenizer (no backtracking)?

Tags: xml, tokenize, ragel

**UPDATE 2**

Original question: Can I avoid using Ragel's `|**|` if I don't need backtracking?

Updated answer: Yes, you can write a simple tokenizer with `()*` if you don't need backtracking.

**UPDATE 1**

I realized that asking about XML tokenizing was a red herring, because what I'm doing is not specific to XML.

**END UPDATES**

I have a Ragel scanner/tokenizer that simply looks for FooBarEntity elements in files like:

```
<ABC >
  <XYZ >
    <FooBarEntity>
      <Example >Hello world</Example >
    </FooBarEntity>
  </XYZ >
  <XYZ >
    <FooBarEntity>
      <Example >sdrastvui</Example >
    </FooBarEntity>
  </XYZ >
</ABC >
```

The scanner version:

```
%%{
  machine simple_scanner;
  action Emit {
    emit data[(ts+14)..(te-15)].pack('c*')
  }
  foo = '<FooBarEntity>' any+ :>> '</FooBarEntity>';
  main := |*
    foo => Emit;
    any;
  *|;
}%%
```

The non-scanner version (i.e. uses `()*` instead of `|**|`)

```
%%{
  machine simple_tokenizer;
  action MyTs {
    my_ts = p
  }
  action MyTe {
    my_te = p
  }
  action Emit {
    emit data[my_ts...my_te].pack('c*')
    my_ts = nil
    my_te = nil    
  }
  foo = '<FooBarEntity>' any+ >MyTs :>> '</FooBarEntity>' >MyTe %Emit;
  main := ( foo | any+ )*;
}%%
```

I figured this out and wrote tests for it at https://github.com/seamusabshere/ruby_ragel_examples

You can see the reading/buffering code at https://github.com/seamusabshere/ruby_ragel_examples/blob/master/lib/simple_scanner.rl and https://github.com/seamusabshere/ruby_ragel_examples/blob/master/lib/simple_tokenizer.rl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a scanner to parse XML. I've implemented a [simple XML parser in](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.rl) Ragel, without a scanner. [Here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1712) is a blog post with some timings and more info.

Edit: You can do it many ways. You could use a scanner. You could parse for words and if you see `STARTANIMAL` you start collecting words until you see `STOPANIMAL`.

Comment: is it too much to ask for an example? I would buy you a coffee and ask you to write it on a napkin, but I doubt you're in Madison, WI :)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Xml.rl this link is broken, sorry.

Comment: Updated link: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.rl

Comment: Updated updated link: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.rl

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing Occam: you do not need the scanner unless you need it.
Without scanner you can process one symbol at a time, possibly reading it from the stream with no buffer.